# API returns blank arrays (ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two model classes, `experience` and `proposals`.

Here is the code of experience

```
public class Experience : BaseEntity
{
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual double Price { get; set; }

        public virtual double? Lat { get; set; }
        public virtual double? Lng { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsFinished { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
        public virtual int CountryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual AppUser IdentityUser { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Proposals.Proposals> Proposals { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comments.Comments> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And Proposal

```
public class Proposals : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ExperienceId")]
    public virtual Experience Experience { get; set; }
    public virtual int ExperienceId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual AppUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
}
```

Experience is related to User model

I need to get all Proposals related to experiences, that have user.

I wrote this method

```
  public async Task<List<ProposalsDto>> GetUserProposalCustomer(string id)
    {
        var proposals = await _context.Experiences.Where(x => x.UserId == id).Select(x => x.Proposals)
            .ProjectTo<ProposalsDto>().ToListAsync();
        return proposals;
    }
```

But it returns me this

```
[
{
    "description": null,
    "proposalPrice": 0.0,
    "experiencePrice": 0.0,
    "creator": null,
    "proposalMessage": null,
    "email": null,
    "experienceId": 0,
    "isActive": false,
    "userId": null,
    "isConfirmed": false,
    "id": 0
},
{
    "description": null,
    "proposalPrice": 0.0,
    "experiencePrice": 0.0,
    "creator": null,
    "proposalMessage": null,
    "email": null,
    "experienceId": 0,
    "isActive": false,
    "userId": null,
    "isConfirmed": false,
    "id": 0
},
```

I expect to have those values

[image]

Where is my trouble?

**UPDATE**

I tried to add `.Include`  and
I tried to write SQL Script

Here is it

```
 SELECT a.id
FROM dbo.Proposals AS a
INNER JOIN dbo.Experiences AS b ON a.ExperienceId=b.Id WHERE a.UserId = '3f4853a0-e310-44c2-a9e5-0c8d1dd7231e';
```

And I have all the values. But on API I have same stuff as before.

[image]

Comment: What is the expectation?

Comment: Not blank values @Yasser

Comment: how about Proposals value before you 'ProjectTo' it. I would check mappings

Comment: Can you try to see values in `await _context.Experiences.Where(x => x.UserId == id).Select(x => x.Proposals)` without the mapping part? Do you get the values here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if you are getting the correct `id` parameter and then in `proposals` variable?

Comment: @Yasser I got correct count of Proposals but blank arrays

Comment: @Pribina blank arrays, but correct count

Answer (score 1):

Do you have lazy loading enabled in your EF configuration?

Try to use `Include` to eager load the proposals.

```
var proposals = await _context
                        .Experiences
                        .Include(x => x.Proposals)
                        .Where(x => x.UserId == id)
                        .Select(x => x.Proposals).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Tried now, but have the same stuff.

Comment: Can you try to write a SQL query using same joins to see if you really have data present correctly?